# Can Fiora be CC'd during her ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I understand that Fiora is not targetable by point and click abilities during her ultimate, but what happens during a type of AoE crowd control, like Sona's Crescendo or Amumu's Curse of the Sad Mummy?

Comment: @user1337 your answer is also correct. Your answer focusses more on  the CC aspect of the questions while mine is more of a general answer. But anyways CC is what the OP asked for ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fioras Ultimate gives you basically the same "Invurnerability" as a Vladimir W or a Fizz E. While you are completely untargetable and immune to AOE you will still take damage from DOT abilites. Also something like Fiddle drain will not be interrupted if it was applied before you used your ultimate. The only champion that has a total invurnerability is Shaco because his ultimate makes him **disappear from the game** for a short amount of time.

You can read about all the different types of Invurnerability [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Untargetable) (the one of fiora counts as a "Dash")

Comment: Pantheon ult counts the same as Shaco afaik

Comment: @eyeofthehawks hmm that might be but I don't have an online source for this and something like a "disappearance" is pretty hard to test ingame...

Answer (score 3):

No, she can not be affected by anything new while her ultimate is active. I will find out if any effects from CC originating from homing projectiles (Taric, Sion, Vi's ultimate) will still apply afterwards.

But no, during the ultimate, she is not affected by AOE, just as Zed, Master Yi, Shaco during their "disappear" frames.

Comment: Same goes for Vi her ulti I believe.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire Vi does take damage from all sources (Projectiles, AOE etc) but she cannot be stunned or CC'd in any way.

Comment: Death is the strongest CC -.-

Answer (score 0):

while she cannot be CC'd in any way during her ult, she can still die (thornmail) while untargetable. and earlier cc that was cast on her(Morgana Soul Shackle(R) to name a few) will resume but will be treated like she didn't ult'd at all.
ex. morg R is 1.5 secs, u disappeared for, say 1 secs, u will be stunned 5 secs when ur ult is finished.